# Troubleshooting 'Column is null' issues using Postgres and EF core

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Been trying to troubleshoot an issue where one of our queries results in the following error message:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Column is null at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal) at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal)
```

Is there any way to determine what column it's complaining about? Usually I can troubleshoot this but unfortunately the query hits a ton of tables and was wondering if there was some magic code that would indicate which column it's complaining about when EF core is attempting to shove it into a model.

Comment: Run a SQL trace while the code is running and see what the last SQL that run was. That is likely the problematic one.

Comment: Execute the statement in `psql`, then you will see the context and all other information, which will help you locate the error.

Answer (score 3):

If Data type is DateTime, then don't keep it null.
Or if you want to return with null then allow null.

```
public DateTime? ColumnName { get; set; }
```